# How to make mysql table column as KEY, when already another column is set as PRIMARY KEY

Tags: mysql

In our mysql database, one table say "mytable" is having coumn `mobile_no` as primary key. But we are in need to make another column also as key. So that I can use that column in where condition.
Show create of table is below-:

```
CREATE TABLE `report_data` (
  `api_request_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emailid` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `api_recipient_data` longtext,
  `request_params` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sent_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `sent_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '1-processed, 2-success, 3-in-bounce, 4-invalid-domain,5-in-unsubscribe, 6-in-scrubbing',
  `api_userid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `domain_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`api_request_id`,`emailid`),
  KEY `sent_date` (`sent_date`)
);
```

I want to add one new column to this existing table and make that column as KEY.

Comment: The table can contain many keys (indexes) in the structure. One of them (or none) may be primary, all another will be either unique or common. So simply create additional index, don't look at the PK presence.

Comment: Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: @Progman attempts we made-: 1. alter table mytable add column track_id bigint(22) NOT NULL  primary key;  I found one article where they are saying first add column then add constraint like  alter table mytable add constraint primary key(track_id);

Comment: Unclear. Show current table's definition and desired final one as complete CREATE TABLE scripts.

Comment: which having around 1m data. we want to add one column d_name and want it to make it as KEY, so that d_name could be used in where condition along with other already defined Keys.

Comment: we can do it by renaming existing table and creating new table, but then how can we put data back into newly created table, so we want to alter table with new column as key and whatever data exist must be there.

Comment: Add facts into the question text as an update - it is unreadable in comment. And do not describe what you need to achieve - post needed final CREATE TABLE.

Comment: 'make it as KEY, so that d_name could be used in where condition' - not being a key does not preclude the column from being used in a where condition and the optimiser might choose to ignore the key. On the other hand depending on the query performance may be improved..I suspect the downvote is because your question doesn't say what you are trying to achieve just what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> we want to add one column d_name and want it to make it as KEY

```
ALTER TABLE report_data 
    ADD COLUMN d_name {column definition} ,
    ADD INDEX (d_name);
```

[sample fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JzaHRppG)